# Does an EC signature preserve entropy?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, entropy, key-distribution, verifiable-random-function

Assume I have a perfect source of entropy, which is unknown to me, and is used to generate a private key (also unknown to me, but usable).

If I make a signature with this unknown private key on a constant piece of data (e.g. `hash('foo')`) and then hash that signature, is the original entropy preserved?

Put another way, does an elliptic curve signature's output probability distribution function resemble that of a perfect hash function (i.e. uniform), or do the outputs concentrate in some other function throughout the space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ed25519 is a typical elliptic-curve signature scheme, in a group of large prime order $\ell \approx 2^{252}$ on a curve over the field $\mathbb F_p$ for $p = 2^{255} - 19$.  A secret key is a uniform random 32-byte string; a signature is a 64-byte string encoding a point $R$ on the curve generated by the standard base point, and encoding a scalar $s \in \mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$.

**Since *for any fixed message* $m$ the key-to-signature function is a map from a 32-byte space to a 64-byte space, it can't possibly induce a uniform distribution on the output space.**  In fact, for each choice of $R$, of which there are $\ell$ possibilities, there is a unique choice of $s$, so there are only about $2^{252}$ possible signatures—obviously, some secret keys share a common signature on $m$ (but there are so few collisions it doesn't matter in practice).

Further, the signatures are easily distinguishable from uniform random bit strings: the scalar is always less than $\ell$, and the encoding of $R$ contains an encoding of an integer $x$ such that $(1 + x^2)/(1 + (121665/121666) x^2)$ is a quadratic residue modulo $2^{255} - 19$.

**Does the output distribution have *approximately* the same entropy as the uniform distribution on secret keys?**  At best it can have about 252 bits of entropy, because there are only about $2^{252}$ possible signatures—but that's pretty close to the 256 bits of entropy possible in a secret key.  At worst it ought not to have substantially less than 128 bits of entropy, because if not, there would be a random algorithm with substantially better probability of success at forgery than, *e.g.*, Pollard's $\rho$ to recover the secret scalar from the public key, at comparable costs.

As it turns out, we choose between these options more or less uniformly at random: the choice of $R$ is determined by a scalar in $\mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$ chosen by a pseudorandom function of the message, keyed by the secret key.  So, to anyone *without knowledge of the public key*: **Yes, the distribution on signatures has about 252 bits of entropy.**

This is why you can make a [VRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_random_function) out of it, though you need a little more work like an output filter to get all the properties of a VRF, so that *even knowing the public key* is not enough to distinguish outputs from uniform random if you don't have the proof of output too.